# Корректный фильтр preg

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
task1_subtask13
```

Анализирую с помощью `(^|[[^\w\-]]+)(task|tasks)[^a-z\-]*(?<TO>[\d]{1,2})(subtask|subtasks)[^a-z\-]*(?<TT>[\d]{1,2})`.

Проблема в том, что `\w`, это `A-zА-я\_`.

Нужно чтобы не было символов, но могло быть -_.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ну так и напишите вместо \w `_`

Comment: А зачем тут вообще что бы то ни было перед `(task|tasks)`? Кстати, это лучше написать как `task(s)?` (можно и без скобок). Разве просто вот это `tasks?(?<TO>\d+)_subtasks?(?<TT>\d+)` не подойдет?

Comment: `\w` это не `A-zА-я\_`! Не вводите людей в заблуждение!

Comment: @andy.37 Если я правильно понял, у него task или в самом начале строки или перед ним еще какие-то символы и вот те символы, если они есть захватываются в первое подвыражение

Comment: @Mike, судя по тому, что только цифры - именные подвыражения, кроме них ничего не нужно, а тогда пофиг, что там у нас перед `task`. Ну, или надо четче сформулировать задачу.

Comment: @andy.37  От гения написавшего [\d]{1,2} ну и task/tasks всего можно ожидать, в том числе и использования нумерованных выражений :)

Comment: @Piotr, приведите пример ПОЛНОЙ входной строки (лучше парочку), и что вам нужно из нее выдернуть.

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял вопрос, что числа после `task`/`subtask` захватываются неверно, только последняя цифра оказывается в захватывающей подмаске.

Правда, в шаблоне тогда не хватает `_` после `(?<TO>[\d]{1,2})`.

Иллюстрация проблемы: [`(^|[[^\w\-]]+)(task|tasks)[^a-z\-]*(?<TO>[\d]{1,2})_(subtask|subtasks)[^a-z\-]*(?<TT>[\d]{1,2})`](https://regex101.com/r/uA8dG5/1) 
дает следующие результаты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю, должно быть `13`.

Предлагаю решить это с помощью ленивого квантификатора (а также немного сократить лишнее):

```
(^|[^\w-]+)(tasks?)[^a-z-]*?(?<TO>\d{1,2})_(subtasks?)[^a-z-]*?(?<TT>\d{1,2})
                           ^                                  ^
```

[Демо](https://regex101.com/r/uA8dG5/2)